# Android SharedPreferences/PreferenceFragment not working

Tags: java, android, android-activity, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I recently studied the section about handling application preferences with **shared preferences** and the `PreferenceFragment` in the *Android Developer Documentation* and made the following simple example:

#### SettingsActivity.java

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(savedInstanceState == null)
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit()

    }

}
```

#### SettingsFragment.java

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }

}
```

#### res/xml/settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_general_category">    

        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="@id/pref_key_apiBaseUri"
            android:title="@string/pref_apiBaseUri_title"
            android:defaultValue="@string/pref_apiBaseUri_default"
            android:persistent="true"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:singleLine="true" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

#### Other stuff:

```
id        pref_key_apiBaseUri
string    pref_apiBaseUri_title       "Api Base Uri"
string    pref_api_baseUri_default    "http://acme.com/api/
```

## Problem

Straightforward stuff, eh? I started the app, went to the preference menu / activity, the *preference fragment* got inflated and I clicked on "**Api Base Uri**". An `EditText` dialog popped up, I changed "`http://acme.com/api`" to "`http://acme.com/api2`" and pressed on OK. Now, as far as I understood the documentation, preferences should get saved automatically into the **shared preferences**. When I reopen the `EditText` dialog, I see that my changes are stored.

HOWEVER.. when I close the activity (or the app) and go back to the settings, again, the default value is back, no changes have been made! What can I do to permanently save my settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your settings.xml, you have:

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:key="@id/pref_key_apiBaseUri"
    android:title="@string/pref_apiBaseUri_title"
    android:defaultValue="@string/pref_apiBaseUri_default"
    android:persistent="true"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

You must specify a string for key, as the docs for **android:key** say:

> This attribute is required for preferences that persist a data value. It specifies the unique key (a string) the system uses when saving this setting's value in the SharedPreferences.

It seems that your pref_key_apiBaseUri is an empty String. Change it to a valid String and move to strings.xml:

```
<string name="pref_key_apiBaseUri">KEY</string>
```

then use as:

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:key="@string/pref_key_apiBaseUri"
    ...
```

OR keep it as it is, and just add `+` in front of id tag, which will create id which in turn will be used as key:

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:key="@+id/pref_key_apiBaseUri"
    ...
```

Comment: I have defined my id in /res/values/ids.xml as the following: `<item type="id" name="pref_key_apiBaseUri" />`. Shouldn't that work?

Comment: I see. I'm not sure why it doesn't work. I can see that in the docs, they just use strings, not references to ids, and your problem seems to be in android:key element, as described above...

Comment: Huh, you're actually right. Referenced ids doesn't seem to work, altough it's funny 'cause a settings key should be unique and hence, an id. Using a string solved my problem, thank you.

Comment: Thanks so much. I spent a bunch of time puzzling over this and alas.... I forgot the key on a couple preferences. Won't forget that again :)